# AngularJS 1.6 Routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-1.6

I'm setting up my routing for a AngularJS v1.6 app, but I am running into a slight problem.

I am getting the following error, and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I hope you guys can shed some light into my error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] <http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332>)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4759
    at q (angular.js:357)
    at g (angular.js:4720)
    at eb (angular.js:4642)
    at c (angular.js:1838)
    at Mc (angular.js:1859)
    at pe (angular.js:1744)
    at angular.js:32977
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3314)
```

Below is my code:

**app.js;**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("app", [
        "ngRoute",
        "app.home",
        "app.products",
        "app.contact"
    ])

    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when("/",
            {
                controller: "homeController",
                templateUrl: "app/components/home/home.html"
            })
            .when("/products",
            {
                controller: "productsController",
                templateUrl: "app/components/products/products.html"
            })
            .when("/contact",
            {
                controller: "contactController",
                templateUrl: "app/components/contact/contact.html"
            });
    });

})();
```

This is one of my controller (All 3 are the same) ...

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.home", [])
        .controller("homeController", homeController);

    function homeController() {
        this.helloWorld = "Hello World";
    }

});
```

Comment: Please comment if you require more code or information. I imagine this is a simple error I am missing. Perhaps I will have better sight tomorrow with a fresh mind.

Answer (score 1):

Linking to the error message:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=undefined

> ### Using ngRoute
>
> In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, `ngRoute` has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x or later, be sure that you've installed `ngRoute`.

Comment: I'm using 1.6.0 and i am referencing the cdn for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was a bug that I fixed within seconds of looking at my application with a fresh mind. Each of my controllers where missing the parenthesis at the end of the IIFY.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Try including the ngRoute using angular-route.js in your view file